# Setting Input Field Value and Allowing it to Clear

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [material, setmaterial] = useState("")

<input type= text  onChange={(e)=>setMaterial(e.target.value)}>


Loops of 100 Inputs (the above input is to set all at once)

< input type = "text"  value ={material}>
< input type = "text"  value ={material}>
< input type = "text"  value ={material}>
< input type = "text"  value ={material}>
```

I want that I can make some of the loops input value null but as long as material is present it is not allowing me to null when ever i backspace the value after last letter it then reset back to material

It should allow me to delete values in some input regardless if there is material value present or not.

Comment: How do you determine which inputs (out of an "infinite" list) allow you delete the values?

Comment: I have created a form to record data for infinite number of rows one column is for Material so instead of inserting values one by one i made a single input and add its value to all the input fields for material its working fine but now the issue is that i want to delete value from some fields and send them as a null but as long as the main input has value it doesn't allow me to delete from any of the material input      @Andy

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. "I want to delete value from some fields" - _what_ fields? How are you working out what fields can have the value deleted and not others?

Comment: all fields are related with one property Material and  and i want to delete some Material fields or Make them Empty

Comment: You're still not answering the question. If you're coding these inputs in a loop what are you using to determine that, for example, the input at index 3 should have that function? Is there an array of inputs indexes that you're using to determine this behaviour: `const arr = [1, 3, 5]` = the input at index 1 3 and 5 should have this function?

Comment: yes i am using handleChange Function on these and storing them along other data in formData array

Comment: https://replit.com/join/xfsjmakimu-walliawan2208     Kindly refer to this its in detail with code as well 
@Andy

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question clearly, but if you want to use every input has own handler, you can create a `<Input />` component, and loop this component intead of input element.

--- change for comment ---

it looks like you wanna create a clone list with a input. you need create a list state to connect the inputs(view) and data(model)

https://replit.com/@x-ray-s/clone-inputs?v=1

Comment: I have created  a form to record data for infinite number of rows one column is for Material so instead of inserting values one by one i made a single input and add its value to all the input fields for material its working fine but now the issue is that  i want to delete value from some fields and send them as a null but as long as the main input has value it doesn't allow me to delete from any of the material input

Comment: https://replit.com/@x-ray-s/clone-inputs?v=1
I create a demo as possible as i can, from my understanding I think you want to create a input with others by this clone value, and you can change others value and the main input doesn't change by clones. run this code, and verify my understanding is correct

Comment: I created a Demo again based on my functionality i want here is the link and i have mentioned the issue in comments above kindly check it and see if you can  help me out 
https://replit.com/join/xfsjmakimu-walliawan2208